# Ubuntu 18.04.3 (server) networking non working after a while

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, network-manager

I have an Ubuntu 18.04.3 server which started to not work correctly after a while. Every 10-15 hours I have to restart the network service in order to have outbound connections working.

I have a website hosted on the server. Everything works, but after a while connections to external websites (paypal, smtp, etc) always fail. The error is that DNS can't be resolved. So I tried to directly ping IP addresses from SSH, but fails too. I tried to dig +trace but fails too. All INBOUND connection (like SSH, connections to the web server, etc) works, but all OUTBOUND traffic fails after 10-15 hours. I cleared all iptables. I don't have any firewall installed.

To have again outbound connections I have to restart the server OR restart networking with 
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` and it works for a while.

Here are some outputs:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo ens192
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet dhcp
iface ens192 inet6 manual
      pre-up sleep 5
      up dhclient -6 -nw -v ens192
      down dhclient -6 -r -v ens192
iface ens192:1 inet static
    address 195.110.124.133
    netmask 255.255.255.255
auto ens192:1
```

```
$ ifconfig -a
ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 82.165.166.153  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 82.165.166.153
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe27:368f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:27:36:8f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 251345  bytes 169997864 (169.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 183239  bytes 92107852 (92.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens192:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 195.110.124.133  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 195.110.124.133
        ether 00:50:56:27:36:8f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 209410  bytes 383378140 (383.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 209410  bytes 383378140 (383.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.255.255.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens192
10.255.255.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ens192
```

```
$ iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 305K packets, 356M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 264K packets, 321M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I really don't know what to do. To me it seems that everything is ok.

**EDIT 1**

I checked system log files and found the moment when outbound connections stop working

```
Oct 02 05:10:16 localhost dhclient[701]: DHCPREQUEST of 82.165.166.153 on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x21426427)
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72821]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72821]: . IN DS 19036 8 2 49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb5
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72821]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72821]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172.in-addr.arpa 24.172.in-addr.arpa 25.172.in-addr.arpa 26.172.in-addr.arpa 27.172.in-addr.arpa 28.172.in-addr.arpa 29.172.in-addr.arpa 30.172.in-addr.arpa 31.172.in-addr.arpa 168.192.in-addr.arpa d.f.ip6.arpa corp home internal intranet lan local private test
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72821]: Defaulting to hostname 'linux'.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost named[979]: no longer listening on 82.165.166.153#53
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost dhclient[701]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x420a5400)
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost dhclient[701]: DHCPREQUEST of 82.165.166.153 on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x540a42)
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost dhclient[701]: DHCPOFFER of 82.165.166.153 from 10.255.243.13
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost dhclient[701]: DHCPACK of 82.165.166.153 from 10.255.243.13
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Reloading Samba SMB Daemon.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Reloaded Samba SMB Daemon.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost named[979]: listening on IPv4 interface ens192, 82.165.166.153#53
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72855]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72855]: . IN DS 19036 8 2 49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb5
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72855]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72855]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172.in-addr.arpa 24.172.in-addr.arpa 25.172.in-addr.arpa 26.172.in-addr.arpa 27.172.in-addr.arpa 28.172.in-addr.arpa 29.172.in-addr.arpa 30.172.in-addr.arpa 31.172.in-addr.arpa 168.192.in-addr.arpa d.f.ip6.arpa corp home internal intranet lan local private test
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd-resolved[72855]: Defaulting to hostname 'linux'.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Oct 02 05:10:18 localhost dhclient[701]: bound to 82.165.166.153 -- renewal in 20130 seconds.
Oct 02 05:10:23 localhost freshclam[929]: Wed Oct  2 05:10:23 2019 -> Received signal: wake up
Oct 02 05:10:23 localhost freshclam[929]: Wed Oct  2 05:10:23 2019 -> ClamAV update process started at Wed Oct  2 05:10:23 2019
Oct 02 05:10:40 localhost plesk_saslauthd[72813]: select timeout, exiting
Oct 02 05:10:48 localhost dhclient[755]: XMT: Solicit on ens192, interval 118130ms.
Oct 02 05:10:48 localhost dhclient[755]: RCV: Advertise message on ens192 from fe80::250:56ff:fea8:c43.
Oct 02 05:10:48 localhost dhclient[755]: RCV: Advertise message on ens192 from fe80::250:56ff:fe8b:e07d.
Oct 02 05:10:55 localhost systemd-resolved[72855]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
```

Why the Network Name Resolution is restarting?

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show you interesting log messages.

Comment: your gateway is in a different network than the ens192 interface

Comment: @waltinator I don't have NetworkManager installed.

Comment: @DamirNemčanin yes, but why sometimes it's working and sometimes not? I updated the main thread with more logs.

Comment: @SebaSbs who is serving a DHCP for your server?

Comment: @SebaSbs just to clarify my question.
You got 82.165.166.153 address but from DHCP server in a different subnet. Can you ping this DHCP when you get the address? If it's not reachable then your server cannot renew IP in 20130 sec and nic just release IP and broadcast a new message to find DHCP server.